# formula field to count record weekly bases

Tags: apex

I want to create one formula field, Which count record on weekly basis,

for Exmpl, Cout__c(Formula field), There is one custom field PAckage_count_c, This field count my all packages using class(This is working fine now).'

So i want my count__c field like this will count record for monday to monday only, On next monday it will reset to zero and count for monday to monday only.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Try writing batch Class -which will run Monday morning and Count record where CreatedDate = LAST_WEEK

Comment: [SELECT COUNT(Id) Sum, Company__c Id FROM Package__c WHERE Company__c IN :records GROUP BY Company__c], This is query i am using in batch class, how can i count in this one for week only?

Comment: [SELECT COUNT(Id) Sum, Company__c Id FROM Package__c WHERE Company__c IN :records GROUP BY Company__c AND CreatedDate=LAST_WEEK]
Take help from here for Date Filters: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_dates.htm

Comment: I check that, But the problem is package is a lookup field, so created date wont work. for Ex, If i add month old package under company object, then it wont count as created last week.

Comment: I didn't Understood what are you saying. But if you are importing Data from outside into SFDC, then createdDate standard field wont help you out in this scenario.  Hopefully, you should be having some custom fields already with you in object - which might solve the issue.

Comment: Basically package is an object and company is another object,  I have created lookup field for company on package object,  so in package object i have lookup field like Company__c (Lookup) . Now i want to count that for each company how many package i have added for a week. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some here and there corrections in it .... because of time i didn't seen/ gone through correctly...... but you will get an idea.

```
 global class CountLastWeekRecords implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

       global final Integer count;
       String query = "SELECT id,Company__c, (SELECT id FROM Package__c WHERE CreatedDate=LAST_WEEK) FROM Company__c";

       global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
          return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
       }

       global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
         for(sobject s : scope){
            List<Package__c> lstPkg = new List<Package__c>();      
            lstPkg = scope.Package__r;//CONFIRM THIS ONCE .....
            My_LastWeek_PKG_Count_Field__c=lstPkg.size(); 
            // will give count of all package records for particular company record.

         }
         update scope; // it will update all Company records with count.
        }

       global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
       }
    }
```

Comment: no worries about the SOQL ...batch will do his job, for which it meant to be created.

Comment: (1) it's probably `lstPkg = s.packages__r` and (2) global is unnecessary, `public` access modifier will do